# ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender]

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j-1.2.17.jar and apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar.

I want to enable rolling files but when i try to startup server y recibed errors..

```
My log4j.properties file looks like this.

log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_SIJ=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_SIJ.append=true
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_SIJ.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_SIJ.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_SIJ.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${rootLog}/agendaNojCRONSIJ_%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss}.log
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_SIJ.rollingPolicy.activeFileName=${rootLog}/agendaNojCRONSIJ.log
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_SIJ.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_SIJ.triggeringPolicy.maxFileSize=52428800
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_SIJ.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOG_CRON_SIJ.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n
```

errors:

```
   log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:327)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:124)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:785)
    ...
    ...
    ...
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "LOG_CRON_SIJ".
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:327)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:124)
    ....
    ....

log4j:WARN Failed to set property [triggeringPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy". 
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [rollingPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy". 
log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the RollingFileAppender named 'LOG_CRON_SIJ'
```

Can anybody help me???

Comment: Well it just seems like you dont have `apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17` at runtime, how are you adding your dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have required dependencies for `RollingFileAppender (Apache Log4j 1.2.17 API)` in your classpath. If any class is not found in your classpath that is actually instantiating somewhere you will encounter such error. So please check the logging dependency.